# Linksys WRT120N as a Wireless Acess Point

Tags: router, access-point, wireless-bridge

I have a Cisco EPC3925 as main modem/router in one side of the office. The office has a long shape, and some of the computers in the other side can't reach the EPC3925 signal. So **I want to use an existing Linksys WRT120N as wireless access point** for the computers in the other side of the office. For that, the WRT120N is connected via Ethernet to EPC3925's LAN1 port.

I want all computers, whether connected to EPC3925 or WRT120N, to belong to same subnet. I have set WRT120N in Settings/Basic/Internet to have static IP, with IP address `192.168.0.2`, network mask `255.255.255.0` and gateway `192.168.0.1` (which is the EPC3925). However, in Settings/Basic/Network, there is a "Router IP" field, and I can't set it to `192.168.0.2` (setup just **won't allow**), so I have to keep it at `192.168.1.1` and thus WRT120N just gives IPs in the range of `192.168.`**`1`**`.*` instead of the range of `192.168.`**`0`**`.*` as I wanted.

I have tried disabling WRT120N's DHCP server as seen [here](http://community.linksys.com/t5/Wireless-Routers/Connecting-WRT120N-as-a-Wireless-Access-Point/td-p/670486), but it seems not to help my purpose at all. **What am I missing? How can I proceed like I want?**

Comment: So, is the issue here that your linksys router is assigning IP addresses at all, or that it's assigning them in the wrong subnet, or that you can't move the linksys router's local IP to the subnet you're looking for? In my experience, you DO want to disable the DHCP server on the linksys router because since all you're doing is essentially extending the range of your wireless. Turning off DHCP on the secondary router leaves the primary router the task of assigning the IPs, so you avoid potential conflicts.

Comment: @Kate, does that mean that computers will connect to Cisco network through Linksys, but still it will be Cisco which assigns the IPs?

Comment: I've tried disabling Linksys' DHCP server, no success. Computers aren't given an IP by the Cisco, they just won't connect unless given a static IP (not my purpose now). So again, DHCP server enabled or disabled seems out of the scope of my purpose.